# syntax error in recursive function for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

Language: Python 3
Platform : Jupyter Notebook

I want to count the amount of messages sent by the same user at the same date and time in a dataframe. I tried to do it using a recursive function, following this example.

[Define recursive function in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022908/define-recursive-function-in-pandas-dataframe)

below is my attempt.

```
interaction = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
   if ((df2['names'].iloc[i] == (df2['names'].iloc[i-1]) & (df2['time'].iloc[i] == df2['time'].iloc[i-1]) & (df2['date'].iloc[i]== df2['date'].iloc[i-1]))
           interaction = interaction
       else:
           interaction = interaction+1

return interaction
```

but it returns this error,

```
  File "<ipython-input-171-9670327f0e8e>", line 6
    interaction = interaction
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am sorry that the question is so basic, but I am bummed. I've tried changing the variabel names, but it keeps returning the same error. when I changed it into `return`, like this,

```
interaction = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((df2['names'].iloc[i] == (df2['names'].iloc[i-1]) & (df2['time'].iloc[i] == df2['time'].iloc[i-1]) & (df2['date'].iloc[i]== df2['date'].iloc[i-1]))
            return interaction
        else:
            return (interaction+1)

return interaction
```

it returns this error.

```
 File "<ipython-input-179-99d835a6b0e6>", line 5
    return interaction
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I deleted colon after in if after the condition because it's a syntax error as well.
thank you for your help.

Edit: this is the error if I included the colon

```
File "<ipython-input-184-041229eea329>", line 5
    & (df2['date'].iloc[i]== df2['date'].iloc[i-1])):
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: check your parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `:` at the end of the if statement

Comment: I didn't use it because the colon only returns more error.